# Chrome extension popup URL

Tags: google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0, discord, chrome-extension-manifest-v2

I am trying to add Discord OAuth2 to my Chrome extension so user can login by Discord account and it works fine. It opens new tab, lets user login and closes the tab. The problem is I do not know what should I put in `redirect_uri` so that after user clicks "authorize" it will go back to popup of my extension.

I tried this one (got it from a YT tutorial somewhere):

```
const redirectUri = encodeURIComponent(
  "https://extensionId.chromiumapp.org/"
);
```

but it doesn't work. What is the url of popup in my extension? I know only its id.

Comment: chrome.extension.getURL("folder/popup.html")

Comment: The popup URL is not accessible from the outside so you can't use it. Try using [chrome.identity](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/identity) API. An alternative would be to use the example URL from the tutorial and intercept it using chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest API.

Comment: @JohanHoeksma I tried that but discord does not allow url's starting from `chrome:`

Comment: @wOxxOm I am using `launchWebAuthFlow` from `chrome.identity` API but the problem is that right after I click aurhorize on the auth page it closes extension popup, I would like to authorize and still be able to see extension popup

Comment: The popup's existence is very fragile as it's closed by switching tabs or clicking in the page so I suggest that you open a new window via chrome.windows.create with `type: 'popup'` and url that is a separate html file, which will start launchWebAuthFlow and handle it. This way the popup may stay open and will be able to receive a message from this window sent via chrome.runtime.sendMessage.

Comment: @wOxxOm Tried that but even if I close that popup window it closes extension popup also

Comment: Then don't use the popup. Open a separate window afterwards.

Comment: @wOxxOm If I open a separate window it will also close extension popup when I interact on the opened window

Comment: Yes, don't use the popup, handle authentication elsewhere e.g. in the background script and then open a separate window with the result if necessary.

Comment: @wOxxOm user needs to click "authorize" on the auth page so it cannot work in background

Comment: First you display a page with the authorize button, it may be the popup, which sends a message to the background script so it will run launchWebAuthFlow there, automatically opening the site's authorization UI window. When finished, you'll open a new internal page with the result if necessary.

Comment: If you really want to do everything in the popup, you'll have to embed an iframe in the popup, and point it to the site's auth page and use a dummy redirect_uri + webRequest as I described in my first comment.